# Is there any difference between "Run Configurations..." and "Debug Configurations..."

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse (Mars, probably older versions too), the `Run` menu has `Run Configurations...` and `Debug Configurations...`, both of which open the same dialog window. The only functional difference I've found so far is that one has a "Run" button, and the other has a "Debug" button.

It looks like both dialog windows can be used to edit Launch Configurations, but it's not clear if there are two separate configurations for Run vs Debug, or if they are the same.

Is there any substantial difference between the two dialog windows, other than the button next to the "Close" button?

Bonus question: Is there another way to view and edit Launch Configurations besides the two menu options I mentioned (and their equivalents in various toolbars)?

Comment: "Bonus question" please ask as a new question then :-) In the meantime you can install https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/LaunchBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one configuration which is shown in both the Run and Debug Configuration dialogs.

The configuration is actually stored in the workspace `.metadata` in the `.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches` folder. There is one `xxx.launch` file for each configuration.